# Android: full screen RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have this custom class ...

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView
```

When I set the `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` inside of the `DrawView` constructor
The `EditText` ends up behind the `ImageView` and `ImageView` fill the screen.
how should I change my layout to place `EditText` under the `ImageView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.hasse.move.DrawView
   android:id="@+id/mainView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<EditText android:id="@+id/addtext"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/mainView"
   android:text="aaa"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position your views by aligment top, bottom, left, right in a RelativeLayout or relative to another child view with

> android:layout_above="@+id/addtext"

Check in properties all layout options for a view.

Are you passing atribute set in your constructor? like this:

```
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
```

Comment: As you can see Im using android:layout_below="@+id/mainView".
But still my custom ImageView class is full screen.

Comment: yes my constructor has that (Context context, AttributeSet set)

Comment: Two days ago I had similar problem with RelativeLayout. I had first to remove all properties for each view then set them again carefully and then it worked, cannot explain why but it works in the end...

Comment: I aligned one view to the bottom first then the other one _above it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the android:scaleType attribute in the ImageView :D

Hope it helped
JQcorreia

Comment: I did, fitXY, fitCenter and centerInside. I still have full screen imageview. Why doesn't the Imageview respond to  android:layout_below="@+id/mainView". I spent all day searching testing to solve this but no luck